# Sending an Object for an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm looking for all Internet about how sending a custom object using an Intent inside of an `setOnItemClickListener`. I want to send this `Person` Object to another Activity, but it's always sending null. I need to put it in 6 EditText different. Can someone help me?

```
listEndereco.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdrressApp.this, EditorPerson.class);
            Person pessoa = listEndereco.getItemAtPosition(position);
            intent.putExtra("pessoa", pessoa);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Here is the another activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Person idPessoa = (Person) i.getSerializableExtra("pessoa");
```

When I run the app I get this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Show your `setText` method .

Comment: The null pointer exception has nothing to do with send the object via Intent. You need to check on which line the exception is and fix it. I did answer the object via Intent part of your question. If it helps, let me know, or else I can delete that answer. I answered the question without looking at the last line on nullpointer exception.

Comment: Here my `setText` method. `mEditText.setText(pessoa.getFirstName());`

Answer (score 1):

`Person` has to be either `Serializable` or `Parcelable` for this to work. Also I would suggest you use `Parcelable`.

Once you implement `Parcelable` you need to override certain methods. You can [refer this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to understand how to implement these interfaces. Alternatively you can use something like [AutoParcel](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel) which does all this for you.

Comment: I already try Serializable the class Person. But it's not working.